# Can 'how' introduce a gerund clause? - "I looked at how politicians purging others."

Tags: grammar

I want to say something like

> I looked at how politicians purging others.

Am I using the correct tense for 'purge'?

Comment: No, but I can't tell you with certainty what the correct tense _is_ without more context (Are you describing something that happened in the past?  Present?  Ongoing present?)  Likely you want _purge,_ but again - context will let us know.

Answer (score 1):

> I looked at how politicians purging others.

is not grammatical, because *purging* is a gerund, not a complete verb. You need to use either a simple verb or an auxiliary verb, conjugated to agree with *politicians*. Which you choose will depend on the details of what you're trying to say.

If you want to talk about habitual or characteristic action, use the simple present:

> I compared cases like the Jacobins, Hitler, Stalin, and Mao to try to understand how politicians **purge** their rivals.

If you want to talk about an activity that's happening right now, use the present progressive:

> I've been following the Chinese Communist Party shakeup for the last year, and I'm fascinated by how Xi Jinping **is purging** his political opponents.

Comment: ...3rd possibility is that OP actually wants to use the gerund, and needs to drop the "how:"  _I looked at politicians purging each other and resolved never to run for elected office.._